# Why there is space in the code example in python threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I am reading the [PyMOTW threading post](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/threading/index.html#thread-objects)

The first example:

```
import threading

def worker():
    """thread worker function"""
    print 'Worker'
    return

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

I run it, and get the result:

```
Worker
-Worker
Worker
-Worker
Worker
```

The `-` is a `space`, and the format will be difference every time

But I don't know why there is `space`?

Some times it will output `empty line` also, why?

Comment: You should lock `sys.stdout` before writing to it

Comment: @JBernardo How can I lock `sys.stdout` ?

Comment: You can't lock stout. You can do cooperative locking by creating a global mutex and grabbing it before each print. You can also import logging and setup a stream handler for stout. Then log messages instead of writing to stout. But you can't control what other modules you import may do.

Comment: @tdelaney So, as the under answer by @Ned Batchelder, see the bytecode, it doesn't suggest to use print in multi threading? To use `sys.stdout.write` insead of `print` ?

Comment: 'print' is more likely to cause interleaving than sys.stdout because it writes in two operations, but both can interleave. The underlying c library does not guarantee that a write is atomic. Its more pronounced when you write more data and it is being flushed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you examine the byte code for a print statement, it looks like this:

```
>>> def f():
...  print "Worker"
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Worker')
              3 PRINT_ITEM
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

In fact, printing a number of items results in a number of PRINT_ITEM byte codes:

```
>>> def g():
...  print "Worker", "Hello"
...
>>> dis.dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Worker')
              3 PRINT_ITEM
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 ('Hello')
              7 PRINT_ITEM
              8 PRINT_NEWLINE
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

To make multiple items have a space between them, the file object has a flag called softspace that indicates whether a space should be output before the next item.  The code for PRINT_ITEM and PRINT_NEWLINE looks roughly like this:

```
def PRINT_ITEM(f, item):
    if f.softspace:
        f.write(' ')
    f.write(str(item))
    f.softspace = True

def PRINT_NEWLINE(f):
    f.write('\n')
    f.softspace = False
```

When you write to stdout from a number of threads at once, these operations become interleaved in random ways.  So instead of getting PRINT_ITEM and PRINT_NEWLINE alternating, you can have two PRINT_ITEMs in a row.  If that happens, you will have extra spaces in your output, because the two PRINT_ITEMs and the softspace flag will produce an extra space.

Answer (score 1):

try using sys.stdout.write("Worker\n")

Comment: But why can't use `print` ?